# Having an issue with flexboxgrid classes getting mangled

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, flexboxgrid, react-flexbox-grid

I am having an issue where using the below `webpack` with the below `package.json` is causing `flexboxgrid` classes to get mangled as shown below.

Here is how some of the classes are getting generated when viewing the html:

```
flexboxgrid__container-fluid___2lUES
flexboxgrid__row___1y_mg flexboxgrid__center-sm___39HWq
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "cross-env": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "eslint": "^3.16.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "flux": "^3.1.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.17.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^1.1.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "sugar": "^2.0.4"
  }
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const WebpackDevHelper = require('./webpack/webpackDevHelper');

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV.toUpperCase();
const webpackHelper = new WebpackDevHelper(environment);

const colors = {
  reset: '\x1b[0m',
  fg: {
    red: '\x1b[31m'
  }
};

console.log(colors.fg.red, `Building in ${environment} mode.`, colors.reset);

module.exports = {

  devtool: webpackHelper.devTools,
  entry: webpackHelper.entries,
  output: webpackHelper.output,

  resolve: webpackHelper.resolve,

  stats: webpackHelper.stats,

  module: {
    rules: webpackHelper.rules
  },

  plugins: webpackHelper.plugins,
  devServer: webpackHelper.webpackDevServer,
  node: webpackHelper.node,

};
```

`WebpackHelper.js`

```
const packages = require('../package.json');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = class WebpackHelper {

  constructor(environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  get entryPoints() {
    return ['manifest', 'polyfills', 'sw-register', 'styles', 'vendor', 'app'];
  }

  get entries() {

    const vendorPackages = Object.keys(packages.dependencies)
                            .filter(d => d !== 'core-js');

    return {
      'polyfills': './src/js/polyfills.js',
      'app': './src/js/main.js',
      'styles': [
        'flexboxgrid',
        './src/css/styles.css'
      ],
      'vendor': vendorPackages,
    };
  }

  get output() {
    return {
      path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'build'),
      filename: this.isDevelopment ? 'js/[name].bundle.js' : 'js/[name].bundle.[chunkhash:8].min.js',
      chunkFilename: this.isDevelopment ? './build/js/[id].bundle.chunk.js' : './build/js/[id].bundle.chunk.[chunkhash:8].min.js'
    };
  }

  get devTools() {
    return this.isDevelopment ? 'inline-source-map' : 'source-map';
  }

  get resolve() {
    return {
      extensions: ['.js']
    };
  }

  get isProduction() {
    return this.environment === 'PRODUCTION';
  }

  get isDevelopment() {
    return this.environment === 'DEVELOPMENT';
  }

  get rules() {
    return [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          // 'style-loader',
          // 'css-loader'
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false,
              localIdentName: '[local]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /flexboxgrid.css?$/,
        use: [
          // 'style-loader',
          // 'css-loader'
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false,
              localIdentName: '[local]'
            }
          }
        ],
        include: /flexboxgrid/
      },
    ];
  }

  get node() {
    return {
      'fs': 'empty',
      'global': true,
      'crypto': 'empty',
      'tls': 'empty',
      'net': 'empty',
      'process': true,
      'module': false,
      'clearImmediate': false,
      'setImmediate': false
    };
  }

  get webpackDevServer() {
    return {
      port: 4200,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      stats: this.stats,
    };
  }

  get stats() {
    return {
      colors: true,
      hash: false,
      version: true,
      timings: true,
      assets: true,
      chunks: false,
      modules: false,
      reasons: true,
      children: true,
      source: false,
      errors: true,
      errorDetails: true,
      warnings: true,
      publicPath: true,
      cached: false,
      cachedAssets: false,
      chunkModules: false,
      chunkOrigins: false,
      depth: false,
      entrypoints: false,
      performance: false,
      providedExports: false,
      usedExports: false,
      maxModules: 0,
    };
  }

};
```

`webpackDevHelper.js`

```
const { CommonsChunkPlugin, OccurrenceOrderPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {
  NamedModulesPlugin,
  NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin,
} = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebpackHelper = require('./WebpackHelper');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const realNodeModules = fs.realpathSync(nodeModules);
const genDirNodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', '$$_gendir', 'node_modules');

module.exports = class WebpackDevHelper extends WebpackHelper {

  constructor(environment) {
    super(environment);
  }

  get plugins() {
    const plugins = [
      new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/html/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: (left, right) => {
          let leftIndex = this.entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
          let rightIndex = this.entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
          if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
            return 1;
          }
          else if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
            return -1;
          }
          else {
            return 0;
          }
        },
        fileName: './index.html',
        hash: false,
        compile: false,
        favicon: false,
        cache: false,
        showErrors: true,
        chunks: 'all',
        excludeChunks: [],

        minify: {
          removeComments: this.isProduction,
          collapseWhitespace: this.isProduction
        }
      }),

      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        'name': [
          'manifest'
        ],
        'minChunks': null
      }),

      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        'name': [
          'vendor',
        ],
        'minChunks': (module) => {

          return module.resource
                      && (module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules)
                          || module.resource.startsWith(genDirNodeModules)
                          || module.resource.startsWith(realNodeModules));
        },
        'chunks': [
          'app'
        ]
      })

    ];

    if (this.isProduction) {

      plugins.push(new OccurrenceOrderPlugin());
      plugins.push(new NamedModulesPlugin());
      plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        minimize: true,
        beautify: false,
        mangle: { screw_ie8: true, keep_fnames: true },
        dead_code: true,
        unused: true,
        deadCode: true,
        comments: false,
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true,
          keep_fnames: true,
          drop_debugger: false,
          dead_code: false,
          unused: false,
          warnings: false
        }
      }));
    }

    return plugins;
  }

};
```

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me.